# Saving an Invoice

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am creating a sales invoicing program which has an access database as a backend for storing product and customer information so that the user can choose a customer from a dropdown, select products from dropdowns, etc. What I'm struggling with at the moment is deciding what is the best way of taking input from the user when it comes to products quantity, unit price and total price. Should I just use a bunch of rows of textboxes? But then if the user runs out of rows, I'm screwed. Another option would be to use datagrid view, but then that means no comboboxes and auto-completion resulting in slower input. Keeping in mind that an invoice would obviously need to be stored and then recalled later, what is the best way to go about doing this?

BTW keep in mind I'm quite inexperienced (as you can probably tell by now) with coding in VB so try to keep it simple so I can follow through and understand.

Much thanks for your time and help.

P.S. Here's a link to my relational DB model - a screenshot from access.

[Database relationship diagram - MS Access](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1uixgyktegmbw45/db_model.JPG)

Comment: As simple as possible. DataGridView in read-only mode. Buttons to add/edit/remove the current line. Double click on a line open a new form with the required inputs to edit your product line, click on the add button opens the same form with empty input boxes and so on. Not very user friendly but easy to code.

Comment: Ok that sounds like a good idea, I'll start working on it. However in my DB there is no column for calculating the total price for obvious reasons. If I go with this approach, will I be able to calculate the total price (=qty*unit_price) and put it in a column beside the rest or something? Keep in mind that I also need to calculate the total invoice amount.

Comment: Add to your datasource a calculated column (See Expression property for the DataColumn object in a DataTable). Sorry but I think you have too many things to explore. I suggest to ask questions on  specific coding problems one by one.

Comment: Alright thanks your your insight anyway, I'll ponder over this one for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relational design is fine, but what you are looking for is a Main-form sub-form setup.

Per your diagram: 1st Create an invoice form that contains just the information in your invoice table. I would use a combo box to populate the customerID from your customer table.

Next, create a second form for your line items table, and it should be set to display as "continuous forms" so that it will show multiple line items. Once again, use a combo box to enter productIDs from your Product table.

Finally, go back to your Invoice form and use the subform control to add the line item form to it, linking it with the InvoiceID field.

This is really a common setup, there are tons of examples. If you can get a copy of the venerable Northwind.mdb (tons of places it can be found on the internet), you can see how it is done.

Comment: I couldn't really think of a way of doing this so thanks for your help.

So I get what I have to do in form 1. But the column with "ID's" in them are all autonumber datatype, so it will be challenging for the user to actually know what they're doing - especially in the second from as Item ID, Invoice ID & Product ID are all just numbers. What do you think I should do about this?

Also what do you mean by 'continuous forms?' and the subform control, do you mean a form within a form? Sorry but I haven't really heard of them before. 

Lastly, do you know where I can find examples of this setup?

Comment: This thread should both give you an example file and explain the whole continuous forms thing. http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/continuous-form-t1949620.html

Also see: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-HA010098674.aspx